# how to Solve it in odoo11

Tags: odoo

[how to Solve The style compilation failed, see the error below. Your recent actions may be the cause, please try reverting the changes you made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRvtq.png)

Comment: Please, post the error text in the question. Also make the title more descriptive of the issue/error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there's some syntax error in Css/Scss.

To fix this just enable the `debug assets mode` and then refresh the page.
Then It'll show you the file with the error on refreshing and then you can fix that error.

I hope it's understandable for you, if not just comment.

Accept the answer if usefull..

Thank you :)

Comment: I solved this problem downgrading the version  of lees by us 
sudo  npm install -g  less@3.10.3